# Define a string in gradle and also use a flavor-specific applicationId

Tags: android, intellij-idea, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I've seen scripts that manipulate the build tasks of gradle and am now wondering if it's possible to set a string outside the `defaultConfig but treat it as default for all flavors.

Basically I've multiple flavors and all of them have a specific ApplicationId. I want to use that id to set a string resource to be used later in my java code.

```
defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion 11
    targetSdkVersion 21
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}

productFlavors {
    one {
        applicationId "com.my.app.one"
    }
    two {
        applicationId "com.my.app.two"
    }
}
```

I want to set a string like this:

```
resValue "string", "authority", applicationId + ".dataprovider"
```

What I've tried:

- If I put it in the `defaultConfig` section the applicationId is still null, thus I get a wrong string
- Putting it to each flavor's section works but since I have multiple flavors creates a lot of code repetition

Looking for an alternative.

P.S. I'm using Android Studio 0.8.12.

Comment: What about in your `buildTypes` ?

Comment: @Blundell it seems `applicationId` is not available there, only the suffix.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Well after a lot of searching I've managed to find the answer to this. Perhaps someone will find this useful.

```
productFlavors.all {
    resValue "string", "authority", applicationId + ".dataprovider"
}
```

This simple snippet sets a string to all flavors **after** their invidual variables have been set. It's kind of like a `defaultConfig` but not quite since it's executed after the flavor blocks.

---

**Extra:**

Turns out I can even set the `applicationId`! My final result so far is:

```
def final String AUTHORITY = '.dataprovider'

productFlavors.all {
    applicationId "com.my.app." + name
    resValue "string", "authority", applicationId + AUTHORITY
    buildConfigField "String", "AUTHORITY", "\""+applicationId + AUTHORITY+"\""
}
```

Now I can get each flavor provider's authority through `BuildConfig.AUTHORITY` and `@string/authority`, which I use in the manifest and in my class file respectively:

```
<provider
    android:name="com.my.app.DataProvider"
    android:authorities="@string/authority"
    android:exported="false" />
```

```
public class DataProvider extends ContentProvider {
    public static final String PROVIDER = BuildConfig.AUTHORITY;
    public static final Uri SEARCH_URI = Uri.parse("content://" + PROVIDER + "/search");
}
```

Comment: My Sir, your idea to add a constant to BuildConfig with the buildConfigField-directive saved my day! :-) I use it to propagate the applicationId to AUTHORITY-class-constants in my contentproviders.

Comment: I just noticed that there is already BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID being generated, amongst other constants for build-type, flavors incl. dimensions and version-info. Nevertheless, I wouldn't have seen that info without your answer.

Comment: @arne.jans the reason for the length of this answer is that I wanted to have a flavor-specific authority, which is also a resource string, so it's usable in the manifest. You can't do that with just the `BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID`.

Comment: Where is the official documentation on this ??

Answer (score 0):

I wanted something similar, so I spent about two hours learning about Groovy Methods. I wanted be able to go against a production, sandbox and local environment. Because I'm lazy, I only wanted to change the URL at one place. Here is what I came up with:

```
 flavorDimensions 'environment'
    productFlavors {
        production {
            def REMOTE_HOST = "evil-company.com"
            buildConfigField 'String', 'API_HOST', "\"${REMOTE_HOST}\""
            buildConfigField 'String', 'API_URL', "\"https://${REMOTE_HOST}/api/v1/\""
            buildConfigField 'String', 'WEB_URL', "\"https://${REMOTE_HOST}/\""
            dimension 'environment'
        }
        rickard {
            def LOCAL_HOST = "192.168.1.107"
            buildConfigField 'String', 'API_HOST', "\"${LOCAL_HOST}\""
            buildConfigField 'String', 'API_URL', "\"https://${LOCAL_HOST}/api/v1/\""
            buildConfigField 'String', 'WEB_URL', "\"https://${LOCAL_HOST}/\""
            applicationIdSuffix ".dev"
        }
    }
```

Alternative syntax, because you can only use `${variable}` with double quotes in Groovy Methods.

```
rickard {
    def LOCAL_HOST = "192.168.1.107"
    buildConfigField 'String', 'API_HOST', '"' + LOCAL_HOST + '"'
    buildConfigField 'String', 'API_URL', '"https://' + LOCAL_HOST + '/api/v1/"'
    buildConfigField 'String', 'WEB_URL', '"https://' + LOCAL_HOST + '"'
    applicationIdSuffix ".dev"
}
```

What was hard for me to grasp was that strings needs to be declared as strings surrounded by quotes. Because of that restriction, I couldn't use reference `API_HOST` directly, which was what I wanted to do in the first place.